# How to format a timestamp range postgresql rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a Rails app using Postgresql. I want a user to be able to select a time-range for a particular day. For example if I am the user, on Monday I would like to select (9:00am - 2:00pm) as my time-range.

How would I then format that to save in a Postgresql DB?

**Migration:**

```
class CreateMondayTimeFrames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :monday_time_frames do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.tstzrange :time_range
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**Controller:**

```
def create
  # The params I am passing in:
  # params[:time_start] => "9:00am", params[:time_stop] => "2:00pm"
  # Sudo: formatted_timestamp_range = (params[:time_start]..params[:time_stop]).convert_to_range
end
```

Comment: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by changing the data-type to `int8range`. If anybody can give the answer for `tstzrange` I will mark your answer as the correct answer.

```
class CreateMondayTimeFrames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :monday_time_frames do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.int8range :time_range
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**Controller**

```
def create
  start = Time.zone.parse("2017-03-26 9:00am").to_i
  stop = Time.zone.parse("2017-03-26 2:00pm").to_i
  formatted_time = (start..stop)
  MondayTimeFrame.create!(user_id: 1, time_range: formatted_time)
end
```

**Test in console:**

```
  $ start = Time.zone.parse("2017-03-26 9:00am").to_i
  $ stop = Time.zone.parse("2017-03-26 2:00pm").to_i

  $ now = Time.zone.parse("2017-03-26 12:00pm").to_i

  $ (start..stop).include?(now)
  $ => true
```

Comment: Don't add an answer then request a solution to a different problem. Ask a separate question instead.